# How to detect that JQuery-Mobile dialog was closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery-Mobile [dialog](http://api.jquerymobile.com/dialog) which I open from my page `main.html` like so:

```
$.mobile.changePage("settings.html", {
    role: "dialog",
    transiation: "pop",
    changeHash: true
});
```

Now I would like to get a callback on my site `main.html`, when the dialog is closed so that I can proceed with the information entered in the dialog.

**Update:** Mentioned that I should receive the callback on my initial location `main.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a quirky way to achieve what I want:

```
$(document).on( "dialogcreate", function( event, ui ) {
    $(document).one('pagechange', function (e, f) {
        $(document).one('pagechange', function (e, f) {
           console.log('Settings closed');
        });
    });
});
```

Explanation:

1. When the dialog is created the [`dialogcreate`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/dialog/#event-create) event is thrown
2. I then register for **one** `pagechange` event, which is thrown when jquery-mobile opens a dialog. So now the dialog is open
3. Now I register for another single `pagechange` event which will be thrown when the dialog closed and I am back in the original location.

Please note that this won't work if the settings dialog triggers another `pagechange` event before it will finally be dismissed. However, this works in my case.

I hope there is a cleaner approach to this. I wonder why there is no such thing like `dialogclose` event.

Comment: dialogclose  dont exist because dialog is just another version of a classic page so page events that works with a page also works with a dialog. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

Dialog is just another version of a classic jQuery Mobile page so page events can also be used.

What you want to use is **[pagebeforehide](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforehide/)** event.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/cbc5q/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforehide', '#second', function(){       
    alert('Close Dialog');
});
```

There are few other events you an use and you can find them in this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**, just look for a chapter called: **Page events transition order**

## Proof

Because you are using several HTML pages I made you a working example made from 2 HTML files:

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>   
    <script>
        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index',function (e, data) {
            var prevPage = data.prevPage.attr('id');
            if(prevPage === 'second'){
                alert('sdfs');
            }
        }); 
    </script>       
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">       
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <a href="dialog.html" data-role="button">Open dialog</a>
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

#### dialog.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>   

</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="dialog" id="second">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Second Page
            </h3>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <a href="index.html" data-role="button">close Dialog</a>
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

First take notice, inside a dialog.html, javascript is placed inside a page/dialog div. This ise because jQuery Mobile strips HEAD content + everything else when opening additional pages. This is why javascript is placed inside a page/dialog div.

This should do it:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index',function (e, data) {
    var prevPage = data.prevPage.attr('id');
    if(prevPage === 'second'){
        alert('sdfs');
    }
});
```

This code will trigger on an initial page, just before it is shown. If previous page was a dialog then execute an action.

Comment: Please note that I am using the ajax version of the dialog. And unfortunately the following does not work: `$(document).on('pagebeforehide', 'settings.html', function() {});` +1 for the insight though.

Comment: Please read my article first on how page events work. First you are using this incorrectly, you can't use settings.html, you must use dialog id or class to trigger it. If it is working in my example it must also work for you. It doesn't matter if dialog is in another HTML page. Also it doesn't matter if ajax is used to load it, ajax is used in every aspect of jQuery Mobile.

Comment: The docs state `Triggered on the "fromPage" ...` but in my case I need to proceed on the original page (I will update to reflect this).

Comment: So you want to receive this callback on main.html after the transition from dialog box (after dialog box is closed)? If this is it it can be easily done I just need your conformation.

Comment: This is correct. I currently achieve this with my answer below on `main.html`

Comment: Ok I have changed my answer, so take a look at those 2 files. Now when first page is about to be shown it will trigger check. If previous page was a dialog then execute an alert.